# Are questions expecting cooking advises falls under the scope of lifehacks?

Tags: discussion, scope, migration

I am interested to know whether [this](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1815/how-to-make-neat-pancakes) question comes under the scope of lifehacks SE. My intentions of this thread is to emphasize user may get better answer if this question is posted in [cooking.SE](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/), because the experts are professional chefs who have more experience.

Or this needs to be migrated w.r.t [this](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75/how-much-of-an-overlap-can-we-have-with-other-sites-and-when-do-we-migrate-ques) as it is overlapping with other SE site.

Comment: what about this question: http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/416/how-can-i-tell-if-an-egg-has-gone-bad-without-cracking-it-open .. it has been put "on hold" because it didn't list what was tried... not knowing what to try I was told to check cooking... is that fair? The answer is an acceptable lifehack...

Answer (score 3):

While I agree that they may get a better answer on the cooking site the questions does meet our guidelines. My understanding is that we need to be selfish with questions that meet our standards and not turn people away just because there is another site that can answer their question.

Answer (score 3):

A question is either on topic here or it isn't. That's determined by *our* scope, *our* mission statement. Whether the question is on topic on another SE site (even one that's not created) has nothing to do with a question belonging here.

As made evident in [our scope](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1217/78), [our definition of lifehack](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1159/78), and [this related meta question](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1222/78), our scope is **physical lifehacks**. So long as the question meets our question requirements, it is on topic for this site and should not be migrated.

As for the particular question you brought up, it is about a lifehack related to spreading batter and meets our requirements, thus is on topic and should not be migrated. We'll have to continue to be careful with cooking type questions, but as Robert implied in his answer you linked, there can be some cooking related questions on topic for Lifehacks.

> Cooking food is not a lifehack — not unless there's something so novel or so unique about the circumstances, that the solution isn't really well-known or already commonly taught in that subject space.

I'd say using syringes to spread the batter isn't well known nor commonly taught.

Comment: The question about opening a can without a can-opener came to mind immediately when I saw this question: http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/423/how-do-i-open-a-can-without-a-can-opener
As you said, cooking-related questions that introduce a novel problem are definitely on topic.