# should there be a well established criterion for voting a question and an answer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was just thinking whether some questions really belongs to a life hack or not. I tried to find the criterion to select whether it belongs to a life hack or not but couldn't find an explanation for most of those votes which we have given yet and which I have mostly seen. Most votes given up are mainly because we feel that such questions affects our daily lives. Some viewers also vote it down but only a few give reasons to do so (something which is irrational and vile behaviour towards community). The complete chaos comes next.

If viewers are voting a question both up and down, what does this implies? It implies that there are no standard rules or order by virtue of which a question or an answer is being voted.

I am asking this question because we must not decide it ourselves whether a question is good or not by just seeing whether it benefits us as a community because we won't really know, whether it does or not? People belong to different countries, their ways of living are different, their culture is different, their environment is different and so there are different solutions to their problem as per these situations.

A person who is living in a forested area and is facing problems from something say for example animals (mouse, monkeys, apes), insects (millipede, fleas, mosquitoes) or any other critters and asking a question related to it, should we consider that everyone in the world face such problems? There are many people who asked questions in which they would like to hack situations related to their social class and background, but every person in not poor nor they live in developed countries where technology has taken core existence. The poor person would expect a different answer and voting down his questions, if one don't like it, disrespects his questions, his situation, his background and many more.

**Here I will give some examples**

There was once a question like this how would we kill a single mosquito. Many viewers voted it down. When I saw it I myself realised that it'ss a worthy question at least for me and shouldn't have been voted down so I voted it up. Why did the others vote it down? Was the question not good, or should I feel ashamed that I have to face such situations in night where it is really a problem dealing with few mosquitoes and others do not. No, I am not to blame. My surrounding is neat and clean. The reason was that mosquitoes were just beginning to rise here due to some drainage problem and finally, we have solved it. One wont deny that a single mosquito is dangerous.

[Here](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/10215/how-to-take-photo-of-a-whole-book-using-phone-camera/) is another link of my answer being voted down but still I don't know why?

If one likes we may start making the criterion from here.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer - No!

The whole point of voting is that it is private and voters make up their own mind.  This has been discussed at length, for example:
[Should we prevent some close votes without further explanation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202734/236563)
[Why do people just downvote without giving reason?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/218390/236563)
To give just two.

It is the process of voting and commenting that defines this and every other SE site.
Votes are awarded (according to the help) if questions or answers are researched, helpful and clear - or not.

As to whether we should be clearer on this site as to what constitutes an on-topic question, then there is already a discussion - 
[Redefining the scope of Lifehacks](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2613/6973) -
where your input would doubtless be welcomed.

Comment: Bart points out that he votes down those which are useless for him or as he think the community-----A dung may be useless for me but for others it may be fertilizers.Rest most of the viewers are just passengers so they support the voted down questions.

Comment: A human may get out of temper,he may get prey to the ego inside himself,if something doesn't suits him he will definitely regret it.No one here is any paragon of virtue to decide whether it is good or not.I would like to follow truth,the founding principles of democracy.

Comment: And Yes I am taking part in **Redefining the scope of life hacks** I have made comments,it might be somewhere just below the main questions hitherto.My question here is just about establishing a criterion for procedures.It may be a daunting task but **stepwise** we can achieve it in a true sense.

Comment: Do we ever research whether a question is well researched or not. My answer would be no ! because when we feel it is not likely possible we gain confidence to vote the question down.Sometimes it occurs that we may not really know its importance unless someone pointed it out.

Comment: Servy say if a question is not good then vote it down----- Are we well qualified judges to decide whether a question is good or not? I have even pointed it in my question.He say that if a person is asking for voting down reasons then one should give----but when one gives no one replies.It happened with me but no one replied so I deleted my comment which now was a mistake.I could have showed you that.

Answer (score 1):

### Criterion for voting

The criterion for both voting down and closing question are a personal opinion related to how well posts relate to the scope of Lifehacks. If you personally feel it is doesn't match the scope, you either vote it down or vote to close it. As a courtesy to the OP you should include a comment when it isn't obvious why you downvote.

The community will then in due time, when functioning, summarize all votes into whether the actual post was a good or bad one. Regarding close votes, the same applies, but in addition the moderators has the ability to close posts directly when they see a good reason for doing so.

### Scope of Lifehacks

The current scope of Lifehacks is formulated as such:

> A lifehack is a technique that can be implemented quickly and is used to make one's physical life more efficient when a more standard approach (as defined by that area's experts) or a product is either unavailable or undesirable. Lifehacks are creative, meaning they use materials that are on hand for uses besides their intended use.

As seen in the discusson of [the scope of Lifehacks](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1217/the-scope-of-lifehacks), and is further examplified through [A Lifehacks Manifesto](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2431/4490). A reversed version, albeit not very long, is in ["Is there anything that isn't on-topic here?"](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3/4490).

But there is an issue related to some people wanting a broader scope, and some not, and I think all agree they would love to see more traffic on Lifehacks (just not at all costs). Therefore there is a new attempt to see what can be done in ["Redefining the scope of Lifehacks"](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2613/redefining-the-scope-of-lifehacks)

### Close reasons for Lifehacks

I also tend to use the close reasons in aiding me to decide if I should vote down a question (and of course these are also used for actually close votes). This reason have been decided upon by the community and as such are to be considered general guidelines for what is considered good and viable for Lifehacks.

The current close reasons are:

- *duplicate of*, *unclear what you are asking*, *too broad* and *primarily opinion-based* as the general close vote reasons
- And the sub list of off-topic variants:

  - *This question doesn't seem to be about a problem.* — Questions should ask how to solve a problem using everyday objects. Questions requesting new ways to use an object are off-topic unless a problem to solve can be demonstrated.
  - *"Mind hacks" are off topic* — Questions dealing with personal productivity and self-improvement tips, memorization and learning techniques, etc. are outside the scope of this site.
  - *Does not seem to need a life hack* — A "life hack" is a seemingly intractable problem that can be solved by thinking outside the box. Unfortunately, everyday "How to…" questions about learning a craft or new skill are outside the scope of this site. See about Lifehacks. If the author can show how this needs an "outside the box" solution, edit and 'flag' to reopen.
- And two general options of belonging to another site in the Stack Exchange network, or other reasons as to why it is off-topic.

---

So the criterion for voting is implicit given through the scope of Lifehacks, but when people see this scope differently voting will also be accordingly and therefore we'll see borderline questions receiving both up- and downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I came to LifeHacks in hopes that it will solve general questions about life hacks that people have found or done. I totally agree with you. It seems to me that the moderators on this StackExchange have a completely different understanding what LifeHacks means as an English work. I have looked through the down-voted, closed, and on-hold questions and noticed that most of them are legit interesting questions about `how-to`.

For example, just like your question, I had a [question](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/10189/how-to-use-vintage-frames-lifehack) about how to use and hang Vintage (really old) frame.

I do know how to hang a frame, and I do know how to use frames. Most of modern frames have some sort of a closing/locking mechanism located in the back of the frame. However, the frame in question is really old and has no visible locking mechanism to secure the painting that sits in it. So I asked what is the "Life Hack" for using a vintage frame. I guess it is not considered an `how-to` or a `Life Hack` and the moderators here do not even vote on closing question. All the other StackExchange sites I am a member of have a clear voting system to close or put on hold questions that are unrelated, opinion based, or relevant.

Bottom life, it is my true opinion that the moderators on this SE website are not aligned with what the users perceive this site to be.

Comment: The question is not bad.I believe one who likes painting and hanging it around the walls of the room is a good hobby which gives a great insight about one's personality.To the extent what I had understood,you were asking about how can you hold the painting and the glass in the frame.For others it meant that you were asking how to hold these things in a standard way but I think it is more about how to hold it using some other methods which we may logically figure out.

Comment: I think there will be no problem in broadening the scope of lifehacks to some extent to include most of the reasonable and justified lifehack questions like yours with criterion for voting.This wont bring much traffic according to the gloomy prognostication given by holroy,but it can be true if we broaden it to a greater extent.

Comment: One who know about art would consider your question as important.Most of the community members are not artist so they shouldn't justify question as useless and if talking about scope,then there are many questions like yours that are off- topic but still voted up.